# Understanding transitive property of equality

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Suppose we have two equations such that neither left side equals zero. Is the quotient of the two left sides equal to the quotient of the two right sides? In other words, if $a=b$ and $c=d$ and neither $a$ nor $c$ is 0, then is $a/c$ = $b/d$?

I don't quite get what the question is asking here. What concept is it trying to illustrate over here?

I interpret it as: if $a$ is 1 and $c$ is 2, since $a = b$ and $c = d$, I should get the equation $1/2$ = $1/2$, and therefore  $a/c$ = $b/d$ are equal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use transitivity to prove this, viz. $a/c=b/c=b/d$.